# add parentheses and significance stars to a table of estimates and standard errors

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown

I have a data frame that has columns of estimates, `ei`, and columns of standard errors, `sdi`. I've calculated the p-values but now I need to transform the data frame such that the standard errors are surrounded with parentheses and are listed below the estimates as rows and the estimates should have asterisks based on their level of significance from the p-values, * p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001. The z and p values should be dropped. I would like to make the table using `kable` and `kableExtra`.

data:

```
structure(list(Model = c("Rotterdam", "AIDS", "QAIDS"), e1 = c(0.2546366, 
1.033, 1.135), sd1 = c(0.1672178, 0.032, 0.119), e2 = c(0.4329284, 
1.119, 1.178), sd2 = c(0.1394704, 0.01, 0.098), e3 = c(1.310621, 
0.927, 0.86), sd3 = c(0.0749279, 0.007, 0.02)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

code for the p-values:

```
table <- exp_elas2 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(z1 = e1/sd1,
                p1 = round((2*(1-pnorm(abs(z1)))), 4),
                z2 = e2/sd2,
                p2 = round((2*(1-pnorm(abs(z2)))), 4),
                z3 = e3/sd3,
                p3 = round((2*(1-pnorm(abs(z3)))), 4))
```

code for making the kables after dropping the z and p values and the standard errors are rows:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')
kbl(table,
    booktabs = TRUE,
    col.names = c("Model", "$e_{1}$", "$e_{2}$", "$e_{3}$"),
    align = c("l", "c", "c", "c"),
    caption = "Expenditure Elasticities",
    escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position")) %>%
  row_spec(2) 
```
````

Comment: I would probably use factors to factor the p values, or perhaps case_when. And either past or glue to do the text bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This achieves what you want:

```
p_text <- function(x) {
case_when(
x >= 0.05 ~ "",
x < 0.001 ~ "***",
x < 0.01 ~ "**",
x < 0.05 ~ "*"
)
}
table %>%
mutate(across(starts_with("p"), ~p_text(.x))) %>%
mutate(e1 = glue::glue("{e1}{p1}\n({e1 - sd1} - {e1 + sd1})"),
e2 = glue::glue("{e2}{p2}\n({e2 - sd2} - {e2 + sd2})"),
e3 = glue::glue("{e3}{p3}\n({e3 - sd3} - {e3 + sd3})")
) %>%
select(starts_with("Model")| starts_with("e")) %>%
mutate(across(everything(), ~ linebreak(.x, align = "c"))) -> table
```

On my quick test - <s>kable messes up the centering when rendered to PDF.</s>**Now fixed**